# Why my pseudo elements ::before can have padding-top and bottom even when I display it to inline?

Tags: css

[image]

```css
h1 {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: "Tst";
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 50px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -34px;
}
```

```html
<h1>I have a test</h1>
```

My chorme version is 109.0.5414.75. Is that my browser go wrong?

I hope someone may tell me why inline elements still can have padding-top or bottom. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why you expect, that pseudo elements will cat't have padding properties?
The box model https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#padding-properties says that the padding properties specify the width of the padding area of a box, and says nothing about that pseudo elements does not have this properties

Comment: Sorry,You're right. I had a test with a element and span element, actually inline elements can have margin-top/bottom and padding-top/bottom, but there's nonthing changed in webpage except background-color. So our teacher might won't us to use it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
top: calc(value - value)
```